# iPhone - Adjusting UILabel content dynamically according to data pass to it

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, alignment

I have a UILabel in my application & have added the label on tableview's cell.

***Label contents(text) is in xml format(comming from webservice)***.The problem is i have to align text
inside label as shown in below image...

[UILabel image http://www.freeimagehosting.net/t/pyxuu.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/t/pyxuu.jpg)

- An ***Expanded Arrow*** should be included at the end of second line.
- The text should also includes '…' punctuation at the end indicating the word is
  incomplete.

Please suggest me a way how to implement it.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Parteek ...
          firstly You Get text size  then set lable height according to text size

how to get text size:- use this code

```
NSString *theText = myLabel.text;
CGFloat width = myLabel.frame.size.width ;
CGSize labelTextSize = [theText sizeWithFont:myLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSize(width,MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

get label height

```
CGFloat myLabelHeight = labelTextSize.height;
```